# Sorting text file lines by a value in line using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file like below, i want to sort the file based on the first value

567892|0.22|060717|abcd
789359|0.2|060716|abd
567892|0.22|060717|acd
437892|0.22|060717|abcd

Output should be:

437892|0.22|060717|abcd 
567892|0.22|060717|abcd 
567892|0.22|060717|acd
789359|0.2|060716|abd

Please let anyone know me how to do that in VB.Net?

Comment: You have failed to explain why the output should be what you have shown (i.e. what rules for sorting you are applying to arrive at that result).  You've also failed to explain what part of the task you are having trouble with.

Comment: Especially if that first column is not all 6 characters thru the whole file, you will want to split the lines - perhaps into a collection - sort by the integer value, then write it back out

Comment: I want to sort the file based on first column in ascending order.

Comment: I have used sort function it is working...